# DRUPAL 6 re-install and phpmyadmin onto server

Tags: drupal, phpmyadmin, drupal-6

I have Drupal 6 installed on a server with phpmyadmin. I didn't do the install of both so i'm not familiar with what was done (although I have installed drupal on another website host... they already had phpmyadmin set up). Some of the files got deleted and now I'd like to completely over-hall everything. There is a core php fatal error. I'd like to re-install the phpmyadmin and drupal and for some reason when i replace the files I get locked out of phpmyadmin and I can't reinstall the Drupal.

I would greatly appreciate direction with this problem. It's a big roadblock for me and I've worked pretty hard on developing modules for this portal site.

thanks
ingrid

Comment: reinstall phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

About PMA:

You can download the latest PhpMyAdmin version from here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/files/phpMyAdmin/4.0.5/phpMyAdmin-4.0.5-all-languages.zip/download#!md5!a01d5b0552f90d6cc1c848c66ca07c2f

Extract it to a new directory in your web hosting root (for example 'pma').
Now point your browser to http://mywebsite.com/pma (your website /pma) and log in with your known details.

You can now access your databases and ignore the errors/warnings for now.

Drupal:

Download the latest drupal version from http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-6.28.tar.gz
Extract it and copy the files over your 'old' drupal files.
You have just repaired your Drupal installation.

In case there were updates go to http://yoursite.com/?q=user and log in.
Do not do anything else until you run http://yoursite.com/update.php